# Cannot receive any mail using default mail of swift mailer in yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, swiftmailer

I tried to mail using default mail of swift mailer but didn't receive any mail.

here is my config

```
 'mailer' => [
                'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
                'viewPath' => '@common/mail/views',
                'useFileTransport'  => true,
                'enableSwiftMailerLogging' => true,
    ]
```

and here is code for send mail

```
\Yii::$app->mailer->compose('deleteMailTemplate',[
                'name' => "Peter",
            ])
           
            ->setFrom("contact-atd@gmail.com")
            ->setTo("Peter.p@gmail.com")
            ->setSubject('Delete reminder mail')
            ->send();
```

I don't know what's the issue please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue in email configuration. Please used following code and check i hope this will work.

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
        ],
          
    ],

$sendemail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->attach(attachment path)
                ->setFrom(From Email)
                ->setTo($email)
                ->setSubject($subject)
                ->setHtmlBody($emailBody)
                ->send();
```

Comment: thankyou but I want to use the default mailer not custom smtp.

Comment: can you check this please ? https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/doc/api/2.1/yii-swiftmailer-mailer